# Why is my for loop running and resetting in AWK?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop, awk

I just really can not seem to understand AWK and how it works. I have this code

```
    awk '{ for(i=0; i<NR; i++)print i}'
```

My file I am reading has four rows with with five columns. 
It ends up printing

0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
3

Why is i resetting and getting printed out different so many times?
I just want to print one time for each line. I just can not seem to understand the for loops In AWK and printing out one line. Also could someone explain to me how AWK works?!? 
I want to be able to go through each line and test an if statement if so print but my if statement will run just as many times as the lines in the program. I have tired looking everywhere for answers but there is just not enough stuff on AWK to find anything useful. I am looking for a pretty straight forward answer on how for loops, if statements, and how printing works in AWK. Thank you so much!!

Update question:
I want to read a file that has this content
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1
2 0 0 0

I want to be able to go through each line and add all the numbers in the row and if the row's total is greater than 0 than print the line if not then do not print it.
also I want to be to just know how to go print a number for how many lines there are.
so if the file has 6 lines the output would be:
1
2
3
4
5
6

Thank you again!

Comment: The awk script you posted would not produce the output you say it did given the input file you posted. Your input file has 4 columns, not 5, and your desired output is for a file that has 6 lines, not 4. It's important to post correct information when asking questions so it's as easy as possible for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk reads one record at a time from your input file, splits the record into fields, and then executes your script on the current record where your script consists of

```
<condition> { <action> }
```

statements. `action` is executed if `condition` is true given the current record. The default condition is true and default action to print the current record.

To print every line from an input file with awk is:

```
awk '1' file
```

since `1` is a true condition and therefore invokes the default action of printing the current record.

For more info, get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins and update your question to provide sample input, desired out, and a more specific description of what you're trying to do if you're still unsure.

wrt your updated question, here's how to do the first part (`I want to be able to go through each line and add all the numbers in the row and if the row's total is greater than 0 than print the line if not then do not print it.`)

```
$ cat file
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1
2 0 0 0

$ awk '{sum=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i} sum>0' file
0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1
2 0 0 0
```

I don't know why the second part of your question (`I want to be to just know how to go print a number for how many lines there are`) is showing the expected output you posted. Please refer to the sample input file you posted and tell us what output you want from that input file. Oh wait, are you saying you want to print the line numbers from the file?
That'd just be:

```
$ awk '{print NR}' file
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: This is the perfect reply thank you. The question I have now is in this line of code ---- awk '{sum=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i} sum>0' file ---- you do not have a print statement how did it print? and how come your for loop ran correctly. I wrote something similar to this and the for loop ran just as many times as how many rows I had so my output looked like your but just four times printed out.

Comment: Read the first part of my answer above. As I said, awk is `condition { action }` segments and the default action is to print the current record so by specifying a condition `sum>0` I don't need to also explicitly state I want to print the record when the condition is true because that is the default behavior given a true condition. As with any language, writing "something similar" will usually produce vastly different results. What you got out would depend on what you wrote and the script you posted would NOT produce the output you posted from the input file you posted.

Comment: You really helped me out a lot thank you so much!! I really am getting a hang of it now.

Comment: @jaypal I tired but I can not cause it says I do not have enough reputation points cause my account is new.